# How does Ruby's block syntax work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in Ruby and trying to understand this syntax:

```
create_table :posts do |t|
  t.string :title
  t.string :content
  t.string :likes
  t.string :comments

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

I fully understand *what* this code is doing, but I don't understand *how* it works. More specifically, I understand that `create_table` is a method and `:posts` is a parameter, but I don't understand the rest of the code.

Comment: Have you read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-table? If so, maybe you can ask about things that aren't already covered there.

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Comment: @sawa i'm sorry for my bad English

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth I didn't ask what that code do , I just asked how that codes works or the structure of that code . I know that code for creating table in database and I have knowledge about migration , seeding etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first forget about Active Record and focus on the code structure itself. Here is a super simple version of that structure.

```
class MyBuilder
  def initialize
    # keys are property names, values are options
    @properties = {}
  end

  def property(name, options={})
    @properties[name] = options
  end

  def build
    # For simplicity, just return all properties
    @properties
  end
end

def create_thing(name)
  puts "Begin creating #{name}"

  builder = MyBuilder.new

  puts "Let user use the builder to define properties"
  yield builder

  puts "Consume the builder"
  properties = builder.build

  puts "Persist changes to #{name}..."
  # For simplicity just print them out
  p properties

  puts 'done'
end

create_thing :bar do |builder|
  builder.property :counter, color: 'brown'
  builder.property :wine_storage, texture: 'wood'
end
```

Please type the code above by hand to grab some feel.

Although the code above has nothing to do with Active Record, it has the same structure as the migration.

When ever `create_table` is called, it instantiates a builder (of type `TableDefinition`), and "pushes" that builder to the block (by `yield`ing it) in order to let user define the tables columns. The builder is consumed later by `create_table` when the user is done defining the columns.

Comment: You could use another variable name within the last block (for example `b`) to highlight that it is independent from the yielded variable name.

Comment: Thanks @Aetherus this is what i'm looking for :)

Answer (score 9):

Brace for it :)

1. `create_table` is a method. `:posts` is a symbol that is passed as parameter. Parenthesis are optional, so it looks odd but it is a simple method call.
2. Everything between `do` and `end` is a code block. It is one of the many ways how to pass code as an argument to a method. Code blocks are great for common case. Other similar (but different) ways to do it is to use `Proc` or `lambda` or `->`.
3. `|t|` is an argument passed into the code block by `create_table`. `create_table` will execute your code block, and will pass a table object as single argument to it. You chose to name that object `t`.
4. Now inside your code block you are calling method `string` on object `t` and passing it symbol as an argument. You are doing it four times. Again parenthesis are optional.
5. You are calling `timestamps` method on same object `t`. Here you are passing it one parameter, which is a Hash with the value `{ :null => false }`.

   - Not only parenthesis are optional, but also curly braces are optional when passing hash as last or only parameter to a method.
   - `null: false`, is a shortcut syntax for `{ :null => false }`.

So all of the above is equivalent to:

```
create_table(:posts) do |t|
  t.string(:title)
  t.string(:content)
  t.string(:likes)
  t.string(:comments)
  t.timestamps({:null => false})
end
```

Comment: "null: false, is a shortcut" albeit a shortcut, it's not designed as one, it is simply the newer ruby 2.x syntax for hashes

Comment: @Koen. Technically 1.9 and newer support that, so it's been around for a while. It takes some getting used to if you're still rocking the 1.8 style but it's a lot less fuss.

Comment: @Koen. not entirely. It is a shortcut syntax for hashes when the key is symbol. You can not make a hash where key is not a symbol (e.g. string, number, object with the "newer" syntax. So it is still a syntactic sugar.

Comment: Thanks @quarterdome for your explanation , It's now crystal clear :)

Answer (score 3):

One of the struggles with learning Ruby is that, like smalltalk et al, you get to pass code around as well as data.
One way you can pass code to a method is with a code block.
You can then call the code block in the method definition with `yield` which says "insert this block of code in place of `yield`":

```
def do_it
  yield
end

do_it { 2 + 4 }
=> 6
```

You also get to send parameters into the code block from the method definition.
That's where the |t| comes in:

```
def do_it_with_ten
  yield 10
end

do_it_with_ten { |t| (2 + 4) * t }
=> 60
```

Note that the curly braces are equivalent to do..end.

I'm guessing that this is the code you found with yield in it:

```
def create_table(name, options = {})
  table_definition = TableDefinition.new(self)
  table_definition.primary_key(options[:primary_key] || "id") unless options[:id] == false

  yield table_definition

  if options[:force]
    drop_table(name) rescue nil
  end

  create_sql = "CREATE#{' TEMPORARY' if options[:temporary]} TABLE "
  create_sql << "#{name} ("
  create_sql << table_definition.to_sql
  create_sql << ") #{options[:options]}"
  execute create_sql
end
```

This is exactly what you're looking for. This is the definition of the create_table method we are calling. You can see the yield with the parameter `table_definition`.